# Call js.erb file on html request (normal page load)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, I want to run the js.erb file associated with an action on a normal pageload. Usually, we do:

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
 end
```

And the action_name.js.erb file is only run when the action is called remotely. How can I change it so that on a normal page load (html request) the js.erb file is also run?

Comment: What kind of action your JS suppose to do? Have you considered using [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event with checking id/class of the certain page?

Comment: It's supposed to load some markers and pop-ups into a map.. i could go the way of loading them into a hidden div in the page, and then do as you're suggesting.. I just thought it would be easier/more condensed (but too good to be true) if I could make the popups and markers objects available from the controller to the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon), which will help you to pass variables from controller to JS. Then simply use DOM ready event on a page to fire some action.

Comment: i think this looks pretty good, going through documentation now to learn how to use it. thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929708/how-do-i-access-variable-attributes-using-gon-in-jquery-rails Can you help with this question? THanks!