# How to include associated objects using gon in Rails/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a note and it has a certain number of attributes. It also has associated tags. I have been using gon to make this variable available to the javascript files of a page (making @note.attributes available to this page).

I can output the note attributes easily ie if I instantiate:

```
 gon.note = @note.attributes
```

I can output its content:

```
 alert(gon.note.content)
```

But, this doesn't put the notes' tags through.. I can't, for example, do :

```
 alert(gon.note.tags)
```

What if I want to display a note's tags, but I want to bring them through with gon.note rather than make a whole other variable gon.tags. How might I do this (maybe some sort of joins or include)? I want to do this because it's better for, say, if you have multiple notes displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `@note.tags` is a `has_many` association (not a simple array), [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) doesn't know how to serialize an array of `Tag` instances.

You can do nothing but introduce another variable:

```
# controller
gon.note_tags = @note.tags.map &:attributes

# JS
var first_tag_name = gon.note_tags[0].name;
```

You may want to use [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) if you need to serialize too many AR objects, since gon supports Rabl.

Answer (score 6):

Rails has a helpful [as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) method that lets you specify your associations, which fields to include, and even methods to include.  It returns a ruby hash for single objects or an array for collections, and this will get nicely serialized when gon calls to_json on it.

```
gon.note = @note.as_json(:include => [:tags]))
```